# Executing a stored procedure with m_ref_cursor parameter in R

Tags: r, oracle, stored-procedures, roracle

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure with a `REF CURSOR` parameter.

My stored procedure is something like:

```sql
PROCEDURE procName(p_in_str IN VARCHAR2, p_out_result IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) ...
```

And I have based on these post to try to execute it from R:

- [Executing a stored oracle procedure in R using ROracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47430018/executing-a-stored-oracle-procedure-in-r-using-roracle)
- https://community.oracle.com/thread/4058424

After many errors I have reached a point where I can not move forward. Thes are my current approaches

1. Attempt 1

   ```
   # Not error but not return data
   temp_output1 <- data.frame(p_in_str = "My string", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
   attr(temp_output1$p_in_str, "ora.parameter_name") <- "p_in_str";
   attr(temp_output1$p_in_str, "ora.parameter_mode") <- "IN";
   rs <- oracleProc(con, "DECLARE c SYS_REFCURSOR;
                    BEGIN 
                      procname(:p_in_str, c);
                    END;", data = temp_output1)
   ```
2. Attempt 2

   ```
   # Wrong number or types of arguments 
   temp_output2 <-data.frame(p_in_str = "My string", 
                             p_out_ref = "p_out_ref", 
                             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
   attr(temp_output2$p_in_str, "ora.parameter_name") <- "p_in_str";
   attr(temp_output2$p_in_str, "ora.parameter_mode") <- "IN";
   attr(temp_output2$p_out_ref, "ora.parameter_name") <- "p_out_ref";
   attr(temp_output2$p_out_ref, "ora.parameter_mode") <- "IN OUT";
   attr(temp_output2$p_out_ref, "ora.type") <- "SYS_REFCURSOR"
   rs <- oracleProc(con, "BEGIN 
                            procname(:p_in_str, :p_out_ref);
                          END;", data = temp_output2)
   ```

   > Error in .oci.oracleProc(conn, statement, data = data, prefetch = prefetch,
   >   : 
   >    ORA-06550: line 2, column 18:
   >    PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'procname'
   >    ORA-06550: line 2, column 18:
   >    PL/SQL: Statement ignored
3. Attempt 3

   ```
   # Bind data does not match bind specification
   temp_output3 <-data.frame(p_in_str = "My string", 
                             p_out_ref = as.character(NA), 
                             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
   attr(temp_output3$p_in_str, "ora.parameter_name") <- "p_in_str";
   attr(temp_output3$p_in_str, "ora.parameter_mode") <- "IN";
   attr(temp_output3$p_out_ref, "ora.parameter_name") <- "p_out_ref";
   attr(temp_output3$p_out_ref, "ora.parameter_mode") <- "IN OUT";
   attr(temp_output3$p_out_ref, "ora.type") <- "m_ref_cursor"

   rs <- oracleProc(con, "DECLARE c SYS_REFCURSOR;
                    BEGIN 
                     procname(:p_in_str, c);
                    END;", data = temp_output3)
   ```

   > Error in .oci.oracleProc(conn, statement, data = data, prefetch = prefetch,      : 
   >    bind data does not match bind specification

Comment: Since you have two statements, try running the declare line first then `oracleProc`: `dbSendQuery(con, 'DECLARE c SYS_REFCURSOR'); rs <- oracleProc(con, 'BEGIN procname(:p_in_str, c); END;", data = temp_output1)`

Comment: Thanks Parfait, but it doesn't work. When I send the declare it returns an error: `Error in .oci.SendQuery (conn, statement, data = data, prefetch = prefetch,:`

Comment: Then I get `PLS-00201: identifier 'c' must be declared` and if I remove c `PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments ...`

Comment: In error above, you cut off the message. What does it say after the colon?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem yesterday, but the stored procedure only had IN and OUT:

```
PROCEDURE procName(p_in_str IN VARCHAR2,
                   p_out_result OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) ...
```

For `SYS_REFCURSOR` types you need to use `NA` **avoiding** any other function, e.g., `as.character()`, `as.numeric()`

```
temp_output3 <- data.frame(p_in_str = "My string",
                           p_out_ref = NA, # cursor var definition
                           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

You must define the `ora.type` of your OUT variable as "cursor":

```
attr(temp_output3$p_in_str, "ora.parameter_name") <- "p_in_str";
attr(temp_output3$p_in_str, "ora.parameter_mode") <- "IN";
attr(temp_output3$p_out_ref, "ora.parameter_name") <- "p_out_ref";
attr(temp_output3$p_out_ref, "ora.parameter_mode") <- "IN OUT";
attr(temp_output3$p_out_ref, "ora.type") <- "cursor"
```

And in the procedure query you must specify **both bindings**. There is not need to `DECLARE` because the attributes are provided by the dataframe `temp_output3`

```
rs <- oracleProc(con, "
                 BEGIN 
                  procname(:p_in_str, :p_out_ref);
                 END;",
                 data = temp_output3)
```